# Modbus gateway and VCOM configuration using Linux

Tags: serial, linux, modbus, tcp-ip

I am connecting a Modbus Gateway (USER-TCP232) to a Linux PC. The thing is that it does not use MODBUS TCP, it just packs the RTU data frame over TCP, so I cannot use MODBUS TCP in the PC, I must use MODBUS RTU. To achieve that, I have got a solution: using a VCOM. The gateway and the PC would be connected using Ethernet and I would use a script with MODBUS RTU communication code in it. That's the manufacturer's workaround. The problem is that they offer a software to set the VCOM but it just works in Windows. My question is, is it ok to use a regular Virtual Serial Port Driver? Can I use any VCOM configuration software in my Linux or do I need a specific one according to my gateway?

Comment: In principle it should work fine, but have you got a little more detail of the MODBUS side?  Is it over RS-485, RS-232, what speed is it?  Is there a reason not to do that directly out of the Linux computer?

Comment: I have not too much information because it is in the design process. It's over RS485. I don't understand the last part of your question, to do what?

Comment: I mean instead of Linux - ether -- converter -- Modbus-RTU/RS485, you do put an RS485 interface in the Linux computer, and drive the Modbus-RTU directly with "real" serial port.

Comment: Oh, I could use MODBUS TCP/IP directly to the Linux PC (coming from the gateway), but the gateway that I have got use RTU under TCP. As an input to the computer I have a ethernet cable (RJ45) and that is ok, but I don't have an RS485 interface in my PC.

Comment: "Can I use any VCOM configuration software in my Linux or do I need a specific one according to my gateway?":  Have you got a link to the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a virtual serial port in Linux for this.

The only trick is to ensure you have correct RS-485 handshaking for your converter to drive its output correctly.  (That is, you have the correct settings.) If you have a working one in the lab on a Windows computer you'll be able to work out the correct settings with an oscilloscope, and recreate the appropriate settings script for your Linux computer.

Consider putting a physical RS-485 port on the Linux computer, and driving it directly.  USB-to-RS-485 converters are pretty inexpensive and simple compared to ethernet-based converters.